# FireFox Add-on permissions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building an add-on as a project  for Firefox using JPM and was wondering how I could enable indefinite permissions for the user?

e.g.

I have the below code which prompts the user for permission on every website:

```
function HTT(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
    body: theBody,
    icon: theIcon
  }

  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support HTT notifications");
  }


  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {

    var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
    Date.now() + 30000;
    //setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 4000);
  }

  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

      if (permission === "granted") {
        var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
        Date.now() + 30000;
        //setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 4000);
      }
    });
  }

 }
```

What I would like to do is ask for permission once ONLY. How could I achieve this as I have tried a number of different options?

FYI - The purpose of the add-on is the display a notification, but this is the permission side of the code.

Thanks

Comment: When you get permission === granted you can set a preference and then in future instead of requesting permission first, check the pref first, if it exists then use that value else prompt.

Comment: Thanks for this, Its my first time using FireFox SDK. I think I see what you mean but how would I set the pref? Would it be via some sort of cookie or database? I was hoping that there would be some kind of global mod that I could communicate with and set my app as "granted". I have just come across the "mozPermissionsettings" API but not to sure about that yet.

Comment: Check out the sdk simple-prefs docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs

Comment: Thanks again. This will work as part of the issue, but I am still unsure as to how I can actually set the permission for the app across all sites?